# Counting grid configurations

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, permutations

Given a $N\times N$ matrix, it's said to be "greco-latin" if each row and each column contains all numbers from $1$ to $n$, each one only once.
We then name two greco-latin matrix to be "orthogonal" if each tuple $(a_{ij},b_{ij})$ is different from all the other tuples with different $i,j$.
(Thus:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   1&2&3\\
   3&1&2\\
   2&3&1\\
\end{array}\right]\ {\rm and} \
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   3&1&2\\
   2&3&1\\
   1&2&3\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Form tuples: $(1,3),[(2,1)],(3,2),(3,2),(1,3),(2,1),[(2,1)],(3,2),(1,3)$ and since $(2,1)$ is present twice the two matrices aren't orthogonal.)

Prove that given $n\geq3$ there can be only up to $n-1$ pairs of orthogonal matrices.

My approach has been to first build greco-latin matrices. We can do it by writing numbers from $1$ to $n$, or in reverse, to get the first row/column. We can then shift by $1$ the numbers and write the second row/column and so on like i did in the example. Then after trying to figure out the shape of orthogonal matrices I fiddled and after being confused I wrote a code that generated a lot more than $n-1$ pairs (I went from $0$ to $n-1$ instead from $1$ to $n$ but that's the same). These are a couple of what I got for $n=3$,

```
[1, 2, 0]     [0, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2]     [2, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 1]     [1, 0, 2]
=========
[1, 2, 0]     [2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]     [0, 1, 2]
[2, 0, 1]     [1, 2, 0]
=========
[1, 2, 0]     [0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]     [1, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1]     [2, 0, 1]
=========
[1, 2, 0]     [1, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2]     [0, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 1]     [2, 1, 0]
=========
[1, 2, 0]     [2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2]     [1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 1]     [0, 2, 1]
=========
[1, 2, 0]     [1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2]     [2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1]     [0, 1, 2]
```

Did I misenterpreted the text? The source is very valid so I don't get what I'm doing wrong/what is the solution. It may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares

Comment: There are at most $n-1$ pairwise orthogonal latin squares.  That is, there are at most $n-1$ latin squares so that each is orthogonal to each of the others.

Comment: oh, and can you prove it?

Comment: A great deal about Latin squares can be found in M. Hall's book 'Combinatorial Theory'.

Comment: This is a standard result.  Any introductory treatment of Latin squares should discuss it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233473/upper-bound-on-number-of-pairwise-coupled-full-matrices-of-order-n/4233837#4233837).

Comment: thank you all, this post is solved